# Why is scanf in a for loop not working in visual studio. But it works dev c++?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to upload a file of extension *.ota and save it in a predefined path. However when I tested it with postman and used "form-data" to send the file I get error 415 Unsupported Media Type.

Answer (score 1):

Add [FromForm] before file

```
public string UploadFile([FromForm]HttpPostedFileBase file, String Type)
        {
            ...
        }
```